# Inbound channel adapter throwing "no output-channel or replyChannel header available" error

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-amqp

I would like to get the message from JMS and send it as HTTP request and in case of failure, enqueue it again to JMS.

I've tried using inbound-message-adapter and message-driven-channel-adapter, but it fails as I get "ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available" exception but since I do not want to reply to inbound-message-adapter, not sure why would I include a replyChannel header

```
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundJMSAdaptor" jms-template="jmsTemplate"
            channel="jmsOutChannel"
            destination="requestQueue"/>
    <int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
            channel="jmsInChannel" destination="requestQueue"
            connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" message-converter="jmsMessageConverter"/>

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="header_enriched_request">
        <int:header name="addressId" expression="payload.getId()"/>
        <int:header name="Accept-Language" value="en_GB"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-CountryCode" value="GB"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Operator" value="Enterprise"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Division" value="CustomerManagement"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-System" value="${sapwebservices.http.header.source.system}"/>
        <int:header name="X-Source-Timestamp" expression="new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(new java.util.Date())"/>
        <int:header name="Accept" value="application/json"/>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="header_enriched_request"
            output-channel="update_customer_shipping_address_outbound_gateway"
            object-mapper="nonNullObjectMapper"/>

    <http:outbound-gateway mapped-request-headers="Accept*, Content-Type, X-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
            request-channel="update_customer_shipping_address_outbound_gateway"
            reply-channel="print_payload_update_shipping"
            url="${sapwebservices.ws.uri.updatecustomershippingaddress}"
            http-method="PUT"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
            charset="UTF-8"
            request-factory="updateCustomerAccountRequestFactory">
        <http:uri-variable name="id" expression="headers['addressId']"/>
    </http:outbound-gateway>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="print_payload_update_shipping" output-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress" ref="sapPrintPayload"/>
    <int:transformer input-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress" output-channel="resp_mapping_json_to_jsonobj_updatecustomershippingaddress">
        <bean class="util.CleanNoPrintCharTransformer"/>
    </int:transformer>
    <int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="resp_mapping_json_to_jsonobj_updatecustomershippingaddress"
                                    output-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress"
                                    type="customer_shipping_address_response.json.CustomerShippingAddressResponse"/>
    <int:transformer input-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress" output-channel="">
        <bean class="transformer.CreateCustomerShippingAddressPostTransformer"/>
    </int:transformer>
```

I expect a success in a normal run, getting error

```
org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AggregateMessageDeliveryException: All attempts to deliver Message to MessageHandlers failed. Multiple causes:
    All attempts to deliver Message to MessageHandlers failed. Multiple causes:
    no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method transform(rest.bbr.customer_shipping_address_response.json.CustomerShippingAddressResponse) cannot be found on bbr.sap.util.CleanNoPrintCharTransformer type
See below for the stacktrace of the first cause.
    org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method transform(java.lang.String) cannot be found on bbr.sap.transformer.CreateCustomerShippingAddressPostTransformer type
See below for the stacktrace of the first cause.
```

Also, would like to enqueue the message again to the jms queue if the http:outbound-gateway respond as null or if the 3rd party services are down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<int:transformer input-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress" 
        output-channel="">
```

You can't have an empty output channel on a transformer.

It doesn't really make sense to transform something and then just discard the transformed result but if that's what you really want to do, send it to the `nullChannel`

```
<int:transformer input-channel="clean_no_print_char_update_customershippingaddress" 
        output-channel="nullChannel">
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Do you know how can I re-enqueue the same original request message in case the response is null or the 3rd party server is down?

Comment: You shouldn't really ask supplementary questions in comments; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. When using the message-driven adapter, it will be re-enqueued automatically if an exception is thrown, as long as you use only subscribable channels (default) so that the flow runs on the container thread.